# SSAS CUBE connection from Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, olap-cube

I am trying to connect to my local database `Comms` from Visual Studio on an analysis services project for creating a cube.

When I make connection on data source and test the connection I get this error :

> Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. Client unable to establish connection Registry information is corrupt or missing. Make sure the provider is installed and registered correctly.

[image]

My instance is configured to accept remote connections with Windows and SQL Server authentication modes:

[image]

[image]

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, I don't see anything in the SQL Server Native Client:

[image]

Where is the problem and how I can solve it ?

I want to connect with Analysis Services.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The latter images are for the data engine, not Analysis Services, they aren't related to the problem if you *are* trying to SSAS.

Comment: Perhaps the host name `MED-JAML` isn't resolvable via DNS? If it's running on the same computer that's running Visual Studio, what happens if you try `.\MEDJMAL`? Instance name resolution also requires that the SQL Browser service is enabled, running, and has been restarted since the last installation of any SQL Server instances or any changes to their Server Protocol settings.

Comment: Thanks for your helps. 
I have changed the provider, ant it works now, I can connect with Visual Studio